# в обратном порядке расположить слово

Tags: javascript

Когда добавляешь цифры в массив он переворачивает, а добавляешь строку не переворачивает хотя видит ее длину

```js
var arr = '1,2,3,4';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
  var newi = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
  arr[arr.length - i - 1] = newi;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто записываете посимвольно в обратном порядке в новую переменную и всё:

```js
let arr = '1,2,3,4';
let newstr = '';
for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newstr += arr[i]
}
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 4):

как например для jquery - `.reverse()`:

```js
var oneway = $('.start').html();
var backway = oneway.split("").reverse().join("");

$('.res').html(backway);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  <div class="start">Lorem</div>
  <div class="res"></div>
```

или та же ф-ия reverse для js:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

function rev() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start');
  var ciao = start.innerHTML.reverse();
  document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', ciao);
}

rev();
```

```html
<div id="start">Lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript строка - неизменяема. Т.е. напрямую вы не можете внести изменения. Копируйте значения в новую переменную посредством конкатенации